# How to use django-filter on JSONField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

`django-filter` works good on all the default fields of Model, but problem comes when we want to work it on postgres fields such as  JSONField

I have the following model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField,ArrayField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    j_field = JSONField(blank=True,null=True,default=dict)
```

`j_field` has data in the following structure:

```
[{"name":"john","work":"developer"},{"name":"cena","work":"teacher"}]
```

- How do I filter the results based on `name` or `work` from `j_field` using `django-filter`?

```
import django_filters

class MyModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)
  class Meta:
      model = MyModel 
        ...
        ...
        what's next?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need to create a custom method to filter:

```
import django_filters

class MyModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel 
        fields = ('name', 'work')


    name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        method='name_filter'
    )

    work = django_filters.CharFilter(
        method='work_filter'
    )

    def name_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(j_field__name__iexact=value)

    def work_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(j_field__work__iexact=value)
```

Comment: TY for the answer, I'm little confused like how to implement this in a view, here's what I'm doing: `https://pastebin.com/raw/zrSAXJuA` , Can you please help me correcting a snippet to implement it on template.

Comment: work_filter() and name_filter() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given on trying `http://localhost:9200/pfilter?work=teacher`

Comment: sorry, add `self` as first parameter. I updated answer